# How can I make a post request to Roblox?

Tags: axios, roblox

I am using Axios to post a request to a Roblox API endpoint (https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/1/follow) but it did not work, it keeps returning a 401 status code. [Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQvjb.png)

Here is my code:

```
axios.post('https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/1/follow', {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': cookie,
    },
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out an answer. I needed to get the X-CSRF-TOKEN first. Here's the code to get the X-CSRF-TOKEN if you need help!

```
fetch('https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '',
        'Cookie': cookie,
    },
})
.then(data => {
  let csrfToken = data.headers.get('x-csrf-token');
  console.log(csrfToken);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```